# Chrome Mobile - Image breaks-out of hidden overflow div

Tags: html, css, mobile

When a card is "hovered" (tapped) on mobile within Chrome Browser, the image breaks free from it's div during it's CSS animation. Can I prevent this? The animations work as they're suppose to on Desktop and Mobile Firefox.

```
.ac-image-cell {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
  top: -55px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #c9c9bb;
  background: url(http://www.nwdastore.com/wp-content/gallery/theme-images/silhouette-unisex.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  z-index: 999 !important;
}

.ac-image-cell:hover {
  border-color: #7EE499;
  width: 170px !important;
  height: 170px !important;
  top: -75px;
}

.ac-image-self {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100% !important;
  max-width: none !important;
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.ac-image-self:hover, .artist-card:hover .ac-image-self {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/dnhmy3Le/

***UPDATE*** Following the answer below, I tried to add the hidden element and rounded border, but it made no effect on Chrome. So I tried a z-index, as well as animated the a link with the image. This doesn't work either, and also changed the orientations of the images which are no longer centered.

Comment: Not working on desktop either

Comment: What browser? Works on Opera, Chrome, and Firefox; Win10

Answer (score 2):

That's because the image is inside a link tag, you can prevent this by adding the following styles:

```
.ac-image-cell a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to impact the issue on Chrome Mobile. Thanks for the effort, though.You'd think with the `a` tag contained within the hidden overflow element wouldn't be a concern. Seems to be something else triggering this during animation.